# Cordova project running on Android and on iPad, but not on iPhone

Tags: android, ios, iphone, cordova, ipad

I have a Cordova project, that I can run on my Android phone using `ionic run android --device` and on my iPad using `ionic run ios --device`. However, now I connect my iPhone 5, and run the last command again, but get the following error message.

```
...
[ 60%] TakingInstallLock
[ 65%] PreflightingApplication
[ 65%] InstallingEmbeddedProfile
[ 70%] VerifyingApplication
2015-06-24 17:58:48.564 ios-deploy[33436:1048931] [ !! ] Error 0xe8008015: ∑~}ˇ AMDeviceSecureInstallApplication(0, device, url, options, install_callback, 0)
Error code 253 for command: ios-deploy with args: -d,-b,/path/to/project/App/platforms/ios/build/device/project_name.app
ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Error: /path/to/project/platforms/ios/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 2
You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project
```

Online (also on SO) I find many users facing this issue with an Android device, and then they need to install the Android APK. I also read [here](http://www.devworkflows.com/posts/you-may-not-have-the-required-environment-or-os-to-run-this-project/) that I have to run the following command first: `sudo npm install -g ios-deploy`, which I did. It did not help though.

I am using version 5.0.0, and I read [here](http://www.devworkflows.com/posts/you-may-not-have-the-required-environment-or-os-to-run-this-project/) that I have to downgrade to version 4.3.0. I find this hard to believe though. Is there another cause for this error? How can I check for it, and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered the same ios deploy AMDeviceSecureInstallApplication error when deploying to a new ios device.  Here is how I was able to resolve it and successfully deploy to the new ios device.  Start xcode and open your xcodeproj file which can be found in your *project_name*/platforms/ios directory.  Once the project is finished loading then from the top menu select Product and then select destination and choose your new ios device.  Then when you click run in xcode you will be prompted that it cannot run on the new ios device because of your code signing provisioning profile.  There will be an option that says something like "try and fix it" and simply select that option and follow the prompts, confirm which provisioning profile you want to use to deploy your app to the device.  If you only have one provisioning profile then select that one and the app will now run on your device.  And in the future you should be able to deploy to this device using the `ionic run ios --device` command.

Comment: I got the same problem. I can run from xcode, but `ionic run ios --device`. I was trying to run on an old iphone 4 (ios 7).

Comment: hi @orlando, you may have a different issue than what is described here, but w/o further details from you its hard to say if your problem is related.  recommend asking a new question on SO and providing some additional detail.